# Batch file to find string "-date=8/27/2015" in a line of a text file and write the line out to another file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a text file and would like to write a batch script that searches for the string "-date=8/27/2015" and write that line out to a new text file.  Here is what I have tried:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (report4.bat) do findstr.exe /m "-date=8/27/2015" "%%A" >>%userprofile%\Desktop\report6.bat

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (report4.bat) do findstr.exe /m "-date=8/27/2015" "%%A" && echo %%A >>%userprofile%\Desktop\report6.bat

findstr.exe /x /c "-date=8/27/2015" /f report4.bat >>%userprofile%\Desktop\report6.bat
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Is the line to search in a separate line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost done

```
findstr.exe /l /c:"-date=8/27/2015" report4.bat >>"%userprofile%\Desktop\report6.bat"
```